# Who placed the mask on the bed in Eyes Wide Shut?

Tags: plot-explanation, stanley-kubrick, eyes-wide-shut

Near the end of the S. Kubrick's film, Eyes Wide Shut, Bill finds the mask he held during the party on his own bed, next to his sleeping wife. Who placed it there, and why?

Answer (score 3):

His wife found where he had hidden it and wondered about it and had placed it on the bed before falling asleep. She knows something strange is going on, and now he knows that she knows, which is why he breaks down and confesses everything.

Comment: I think, Alice; Bill's wife was also there at the party and took the mask while Bill was exiting the House. It is shown that Bill was holding the mask in his hand before going out, probably he left somewhere around. Eyes Wide Shut is based on a German novel, written by an Austrian writer Arthur Schnitzler.